# Find if the Values in a Column of One .csv file are available in other .csv file Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have just started working on Python.

I have two files as below,

File-1.txt

```
ID|NAME|SERVICE
00:11:22:33:44|BTS|24
00:11:22:33:44|EXXO|25
00:11:22:33:44|BP|21
00:11:22:33:44|MNM|2
11:22:33:44:55|BP|21
11:22:33:44:55|KP|3
11:22:33:44:55|SA|33
22:33:44:55:66|BTS|24
33:44:55:66:77|ZZ|242
```

File-2.csv

```
ID,NAME,SERVICE,CONT,NAT
123456,BP,24,NAM,CAN
123456,EXXO,25,NAM,CAN
00:11:22:33:44,BTS,ASI,PAK
00:11:22:33:44,EXXO,ASI,PAK
00:11:22:33:44,BP,ASI,PAK
11:22:33:44:55,BP,AU,NZ
11:22:33:44:55,KP,AU,NZ
11:22:33:44:55,ZA,AU,NZ
```

I need to find:

1. Which IDs in First File are available in the Second File and save the results as IDs_In_First_Not_in_Second.csv.
2. Which IDs in Second File are available in the First File and save the results as IDs_In_Second_Not_in_First.csv.
3. If the ID is in both the files, then the verification of the services is to be done.

The result should be in a .csv file like below.

```
ID,NAME,SERVICE,REMARK
00:11:22:33:44,BTS,IN_BOTH
00:11:22:33:44,EXXO,IN_BOTH
00:11:22:33:44,BP,IN_BOTH
00:11:22:33:44,MNM,ONLY_IN_FIRST
11:22:33:44:55,BP,IN_BOTH
11:22:33:44:55,KP,IN_BOTH
11:22:33:44:55,SA,ONLY_IN_FIRST
11:22:33:44:55,ZA,ONLY_IN_SECOND
```

Can not share a code, because most of the coding I have done, is giving wrong results.

Comment: Did you import them? Do you have them as dataframes?

Comment: No, I haven't modified them.

Comment: If you have some extra rows in your final result is it ok?

Comment: Extra means?  If you mean to say rows unique to any of the files?  It is ok as long as the have specific remarks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try outer merge on 'ID' and 'SERVICE':

```
out=df1.merge(df2[['ID','SERVICE']],indicator=True,how='outer',on='ID')
d={'both':'IN_BOTH','left_only':'ONLY_IN_FIRST','right_only':'ONLY_IN_SECOND'}
out['_merge']=out['_merge'].map(d)
out=out.drop_duplicates(ignore_index=True).rename(columns={'_merge':'REMARKS'})
```

output of `out`:

```
    ID              NAME    REMARKS
0   00:11:22:33:44  BTS     IN_BOTH
1   00:11:22:33:44  EXXO    IN_BOTH
2   00:11:22:33:44  BP      IN_BOTH
3   00:11:22:33:44  MNM     IN_BOTH
4   11:22:33:44:55  BP      IN_BOTH
5   11:22:33:44:55  KP      IN_BOTH
6   11:22:33:44:55  SA      IN_BOTH
7   22:33:44:55:66  BTS     ONLY_IN_FIRST
8   33:44:55:66:77  ZZ      ONLY_IN_FIRST
9   123456          NaN     ONLY_IN_SECOND
```

Note:

```
#df1 is File-1.txt
#df2 is File-2.csv
```

Comment: Away from keyboard now, will test first thing in the morning, but is it possible to get the Name for IDs which are ONLY_IN_SECOND? And Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: @ForrestSunday Yes it is possible but in df2 there are 2 rows associate with ID 123456....so from which row you want to get value?

Comment: Both or none. I am not getting!  Where are you comparing the services in the code?

Comment: @ForrestSunday In your question you mention that you need only ID so we are not comparing services

Comment: Ohhh,  In Third part "If the ID is in both the files, then the verification of the services is to be done." The ' verification of the services' is  where we need to compare services.

Comment: @ForrestSunday after comparing what you want to do?

Comment: The remark will be based on the availability of the service in the file, not the ID; as the IDs are supposed to be in both the files.

Comment: @ForrestSunday updated answer....kindly have a look ***:)***